# Change the value of 100% volume?

Tags: gnome, alsa, volume-control

In the sound settings, the 100% value of my speakers volume seems a bit lower than it could be (in fact, on Windows it is higher) and I can go higher without affecting sound quality (actually making it better, because then I can hear the bass ;]).

This is an acceptable 100% value:
[image]

Is it possible to change this 100% threshold, so I can go to a higher volume using the `Vol +` keys, without the need to always go to the sound settings?

I am using Ubuntu GNOME 15.04 64-bits.

Comment: I would file a bug. On Ubuntu we have an option "allow louder than 100%" and the vol + key does go over 100% when this is active.

Comment: not at gnome UI. it works at unit one.